# How to access ASP.NET Swagger API published in Docker?

Tags: asp.net, docker, api, swagger

I have made an ASP.NET API with scaffolding. I have generated a docker file in Visual Studio 2019:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CoinAPI.csproj", "CoinAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CoinAPI/CoinAPI.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/CoinAPI"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "CoinAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CoinAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoinAPI.dll"]
```

I am building the project with command:

```
docker build -t coinapi .
```

And running it with:

```
docker run -dp 12344:12344 coinapi
```

The container is running in docker desktop in Windows, but when I access `localhost:12344` I get an error 404. After adding this line of code `webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:12344");` in Program.cs file, I am getting an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when accessing the URL. What can I do to successfully access my Swagger API run in a docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that did the trick was to change `webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:12344");` to `webBuilder.UseUrls("http://+:12344");` and now the API works and I can connect to it via the browser with http://localhost:12344/

Answer (score 2):

The application listens to ports `80` and `443` by default, try this

```
docker run -dp 12344:80 coinapi
```

And you should access the web with `http://localhost:12344`

Comment: Running it with your given command also produces error 404.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:12344/WeatherForecast`, the default controller

Comment: Besides, If you want to access  `http://localhost:14333/swagger/index.html` , you can commit the "if (env.IsDevelopment())"  in the `Startup.cs` to enable Swagger UI.

Comment: running the docker container with second port set to 80 was a part of the solution.